# Using R, how to estimate a distribution using known mean, median, percentile?

Tags: r, statistics

How can I estimate a distribution if I know my sample size is 449, the mean is 81.69, the median is 81.68, the 30th percentile is 79.43, and the 90th percentile is 85.06?

Comment: What does it mean to "*estimate* a distribution" in this context? Typically, we say we want to estimate a distribution when we *don't* know these values.

Comment: Thanks for your response. See what I mean by how in the dark I am? I have these numbers on a scorecard, and I wondered if I could use them to recreate the data that was used to arrive at these scores. I don't mean the exact, actual, original data, but an approximation generated backwards from these scores. Then I could look at a good guess at what the 75th percentile would have been.

Comment: So is your goal to estimate what the (unknown to you) value at the 75th %ile is?

Comment: Essentially, yes. Or any other--50th, 25th, etc. And to a lesser degree see the entire sample to play with in other ways. Again, thank you for taking the time to help me clarify this.

Comment: How is it that you have these numbers & (apparently) no other information about the data or their distribution?

Comment: It's a quality performance report that I was given strictly as informational. I really have no idea where the original data came from. I was looking at it and became curious about finding other information or reverse engineering the results to estimate the original data. It's really just an exercise in the procedure rather than a need to know the specific numbers.

Comment: Voting to reopen on grounds that it seemed reasonably clear what was needed (and it go a sensible reply), even if the statistical terminology could have been improved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The highest entropy distribution with known mean and variance is the normal distribution giving us a rationale to use it here provided the data is not inconsistent with it.  Now using the given mean and estimating the standard deviation as:

```
q30 <- 79.43
q90 <- 85.06
SD <- (q90 - q30) / (qnorm(.9) - qnorm(.3))
```

we get the normal distribution with mean 81.69 and standard deviation `SD`.  Here we have used the mean we were given, simply noted that the median being nearly identical to the mean is not inconsistent with the normal distribution and we used the two remaining quantiles to estimate the standard deviation.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This makes sense to me, and all the responses are helping me to get a better grasp on the language involved. Follow up: I ran it, recreated the data set, checked percentiles with the knowns and they matched. PERFECT!

Answer (score 3):

The size of your sample is irrelevant to this question (it might be useful in calculating confidence intervals).  What you have to work with is three quantiles (mean, 30th and 90th).  Since the median is practically the same as the mean, that's a hint that your distribution is most likely symmetric.  After that, you're pretty much dead-ended.  You can fit those data points to a gaussian, or a supergaussian (or whatever exp(x^4) is called), or any number of decaying symmetric distributions.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I don't fully understand what you've said, but I have a tenuous grasp, and that's a start. Don't be surprised if you see more poorly worded stats questions in the near future...hopefully getting clearer as they go.